Which use foregroundServiceType to MESSAGE_EVENT in Android target SDK34?
I migrate TargetSDK34 in Android.
AndroidManifest  tag occured error line.
So I had search Android Document and that was confused to me what I use it?.
Message_EVENT is which I use dataSync or remoteMessaging or something else?
Please suggestion solved way for me!
Thanks!
    <service android:name=".Push.PushIntentService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync" >   <!--here!!-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>



What is the use case of your foreground service? Data sync or remote messaging?

That Code is example.

I wonder which use foregroundServiceType at Push Messaging Service

If your foreground service is used for:

"Transfer text messages from one device to another. Assists with
continuity of a user's messaging tasks when they switch devices."
Reference

then you need to mark it's type as remoteMessaging
You do this by doing three things:

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, you add the foregroundServiceType attribute with the value of remoteMessaging

You need to add the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file FOREGROUND_SERVICE_REMOTE_MESSAGING. This permission's level is normal so there is no need to do anything else

When you start the foreground service with startForeground, pass the following constant as the third argument there FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_REMOTE_MESSAGING


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_REMOTE_MESSAGING"/>

 <service
        android:name=".YourServiceName"
        android:foregroundServiceType="remoteMessaging"
        android:exported="false">


PushMessageService uses foreground type and remoteMessaging, right~?.

Oh I can not upvoted.. receive message this.
Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

@Neander - what do you mean by "PushMessageService uses foreground type and remoteMessaging"? The foregroundType should be remoteMessaging.

Thanks @tomerpacific now I did upvote to you!
see you again later!
